# Predicting the Nth combination in sequence of A and B

Tags: permutations, combinations

First I need a way of generating every possible combination of As and Bs in an array of 2048 items. 
Once I have that would it be possible to row N without action generating every row between 0 and N?

Answer (score 0):

[Edited] If I understand your question correctly, all you have to do is count from 0 to 2^2048 -1 in binary, then replace 0 and 1 in the binary string with A and B, respectively.  (I'll be waiting in the car while you do this.)  To get row N, just convert N to binary, assuming you start counting the rows with 0.

Comment: A nit-you need to count from $0$ to $2047$, as $2048$ has one bit too many. If you ignore the carry bit, you get what you want.

Comment: I am not sure you guys understood what I meant.
Ex: "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA..." (Consider the full 2048 chars)
That would be row 0 (or 1) then next could be "AAAAAAAAAAA..B" and so on, now I want to know what row N is without having to go from zero to N to find out.

Comment: Counting from 0 2047 would not be all since, the possible combinations I believe is something like 2^2048, which might be impossible to count since it equates to 3.231700607131100730071487668867e+616

Comment: @Oakcool, you're right, I misread the question and will edit my answer accordingly.  You would have to count from 0 to 2^2048 - 1.  Is that impossible?  Well, if it is, any other way of generating all the combinations is equally impossible, because that's how many there are.